# Hide button after clicked

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to hide a button (not inside form tags) after it has been clicked.
Once the form is shown, there is no use for the button. So i would like to hide it after clicked

Here's the existing code.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function(){
  var button = document.getElementById("info");
   var myDiv = document.getElementById("myDiv");

   function show() {
       myDiv.style.visibility = "visible";
   }

   function hide() {
       myDiv.style.visibility = "hidden";
   }

   function toggle() {
       if (myDiv.style.visibility === "hidden") {
           show();
       } else {
           hide();
       }
   }

   hide();

   button.addEventListener("click", toggle, false);
 });
</script>
```

```html
<input id="info" type="button" value="Имате Въпрос?" class="switchbuton">
```

Comment: By the way, I suppose you are using the third-party library for switch button, so, the class attribute might be `"switchbutton"`.

Comment: Also, please, describe what exactly doesn't work (do you receive any error, or your block just doesn't hide)

Comment: Does this suits your requirement... http://jsfiddle.net/5epLf928/1/ ?

Comment: I think the problem is in how you're wrapping the function... look at uzay's answer

Answer (score 2):

You can use jQuery [hide](http://api.jquery.com/hide/)

```
$("#myDiv").hide() // to hide the div
```

and [show](http://api.jquery.com/show/) like

```
$("#myDiv").show() // to show the div
```

Or [toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) to toggle the visibility of dom elements

```
$("#myDiv").toggle() // to toggle the visibility
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check the result here:

http://jsfiddle.net/jsfiddleCem/33axo20f/2/

Code is:

```
<style>
.showButon{
    background:url('http://spacetelescope.github.io/understanding-json-schema/_static/pass.png');
    background-repeat:repeat-y;
    height:30px;
    text-indent:20px;
}
</style>

<div id="myDiv">
    <input id="info" type="button" value="Имате Въпрос?" class="showButon" />
</div>

(function(){
var button = document.getElementById("info");
    var myDiv = document.getElementById("myDiv");

    function toggle() {
        if (myDiv.style.visibility === "hidden") {
            myDiv.style.visibility = "visible";
        } else {
            myDiv.style.visibility = "hidden";
        }
    }

    button.addEventListener("click", toggle, false);
})()
```

Comment: Thanks it works. How can i add an image to the button?

Comment: @Mo-Alanteh, check it again please.

Comment: @Mo-Alanteh accept i as a answer by clicking on right symbol so it will help to another people.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $('#info').click(function() {
            $(this).hide();
        });
    });
</script>

<input id="info" type="button" value="Имате Въпрос?" class="switchbuton">
```